# Convert a degree 3 cubic Nurbs Curve to Catmull-Rom?

Tags: bezier, curve, cubic-spline, nurbs, catmull-rom-curve

Is there a way to convert a degree 3 cubic Nurbs curve to a Catmull-Rom curve?

The Nurbs curve has a standard knot vector, so for example a curve with 10 control points has these 12 knots:

```
[ 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 7 7 ]
```

I assume the resulting Catmull-Rom curve would have 12 control points? Or even more..?

If it is not possible to one-to-one convert, is there a good algorithm to get at least a very close match?

Comment: What is the reason that you want to do such a conversion? Catmull-Rom spline is not a general format accepted by different software. Typically, it is used to construct a curve interpolating the input points and the curve is represented as multiple Bezier curves.